# Is there any program that genuinely recreates the functionality of file types in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-types

I downloaded about 5 programs and none of them are like the file options in windows 7. In particular you can't give arguments to commands that you're going to open the program with.

I tried writing registry files myself, and it's an incredible nightmare. Most of the time I try it now nothing happens, other times everything is changed after I restart my computer. I just want file options, I can't understand why Windows 7 doesn't have that basic tool!!

Comment: your question doesnt make any sense.  what are you trying to do?

Comment: This is a bit too "enthusiastic" to work out exactly what your problem is. Please edit your question to describe what exactly you are trying to achieve.  I do not know what you mean by "none of them are like the file options".

Comment: @user279040 Something like a context menu handler ? For Eg:"Edit" when right clicking one a text file.

Comment: The old file type associations menu's have been gone for some time (XP was the last), and now MS wants you to use the Open With menu or the Control panel Default Programs applet, neither of which provide advanced configuration like `start in` or `arguments` (or the ability to type in the command manually). see this question for some options on editing advanced association properties: http://superuser.com/questions/136133/how-do-i-set-advanced-file-associations-in-windows-7

Comment: I'm pretty sure what OP want this: http://www.latenightpc.com/img/windows-explorer-folder-options-dialog-file-types-3.png

Comment: @user also check out `ftype` and `assoc` commands http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/assocftype.htm http://commandwindows.com/assoc.htm?ModPagespeed=noscript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind a file type to be opened with command-line options?](http://superuser.com/questions/675842/how-to-bind-a-file-type-to-be-opened-with-command-line-options)

Answer (score 0):

Files are in 2 category types : 1. binary 2. text. binary editors .

> 

You can't edit binary file without advanced but you can edit all text files in any text editor like notepad.
now, i think if you could recognize your files types that you just downloaded, you can edit them by right tools. for example if your files are in text category you need just right click on it->Open with...->choose default program and just select a text editor like notepad.

Comment: [`;-)`](http://superuser.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I use the tool [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) to fix file associations, change icons or add new commands when I rightclick on a file.