# Automatically open a file when gnuplot starts on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, gnuplot

I would like to assign gnuplot to `.gnuplot` files (gnuplot scripts) on Windows 8.1, in such a way that the gnuplot environment starts with the script file loaded.

For this I would need to pass the path of script file to `wgnuplot_pipes.exe`. Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation about gnuplot command line arguments on Windows.

The closest I could find is a way to automatically render a .gnuplot file from the command line:

```
wgnuplot_pipes.exe -persist test.gnuplot
```

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328603/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-to-gnuplot

Comment: Not sure how that helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general in `gnuplot` there are at least 5 mode to make persistent the execution of a script, from inside and from command line

1. Put a `pause -1` after the `plot` command in the file, or **at the file end**.
2. Use command `gnuplot filename.gp -` (yes, dash is the last parameter) to stay in the interactive regime when the script completes.
3. Run gnuplot as `gnuplot -persist`
4. On Windows you can also use either `gnuplot -persist` or `gnuplot /noend`.
5. Give the `persist` option as part of the `set terminal` command.
   e.g. `set terminal wxt enhanced **persist**`

As you can notice some of them are **inside the script** and are **not operative system dependent,**
some other have to be used following the general rules for associating files to extension on each specific subversion of Windows.
If you are not able to pass parameter to the program associated with `gnuplot.exe`, maybe because a lack of privilege (if restricted to the Administrator), you can always modify the script inside following [1] or [5].

Some references and notes:

- A compilation of way to do associate extension with the execution of a program: [How to bind a file type to be opened with command-line options?](https://superuser.com/questions/675842/how-to-bind-a-file-type-to-be-opened-with-command-line-options)
- For windows 7 but with answer valid to windows 8 too, [How do I set advanced file associations in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/136133/how-do-i-set-advanced-file-associations-in-windows-7)
- From the following instead you can adapt the method for file without extension to any extension you want (.gnuplot included) [How to set the default program for opening files without an extension in Windows?](https://superuser.com/a/13947/257269)
- The always useful [gnuplot FAQ](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html)
- Under windows you should use `gnuplot.exe` instead of `gnuplot`

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot the #6, that works under Linux. To make executable the script "chmod u+x myscript.gnuplot" and to add as a *shebang* the 1st line `#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist`. The path depends from the system.